# RegionInfo as a reliable source for currency formatting

Tags: .net

We are investigating how best to store currency information, including display format and importantly the number of decimal places.  This data is available between RegionInfo and CultureInfo in .Net, but I'm not convinced that this data is reliable, given the volatile nature of countries like Zimbabwe (Zim is actually currently up-to-date with USD).  However, it seems unwise to replicate behaviour and data that these classes already provide.

Is there any good reason to avoid RegionInfo/CultureInfo and rather replicate and customise the data they provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We implemented the solution and it turns out that the data is not reliable.  First of all, older versions of .NET have a limited set of cultures and countries, and newer versions have a large set but which are still not complete.  For instance, we couldn't find the right settings for Haiti and Tahiti.